# Android SMS Delivery Intent always return -1

Tags: android-intent, sms

I'm facing a weird problem on Android. I want to listen for a delivery intent when I send a text message through my app. Here is what I've done so far:

```
private void shootSMS(String number,long currentTime){
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SentBroadcastReceiver.SENT_ACTION);
    Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(DeliveredBroadcastReceiver.DELIVERED_ACTION);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("num",number);
    b.putString("record_time",currentTime+"");

    sentIntent.putExtras(b);
    deliveredIntent.putExtras(b);


    PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,(int)currentTime,sentIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    PendingIntent deliveredPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,(int)currentTime,deliveredIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,getString(R.string.app_name),sentPendingIntent,deliveredPendingIntent);

}
```

Now the problem is that when the `onReceive()` methods of my broadcast receivers are called I call the `getResultCode()` method, and it always return -1! Even if the phone is turned off, so it makes it impossible to track whether the SMS is delivered or not!

I checked the number with the GoSMSPro and sent a SMS which failed. The interesting thing is that when I put my phone in Airplane Mode I get a  Result Code equal to `2` which is `SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF`

Now the question is what's wrong in here?

Comment: I would like to know this as well. I am always getting Result.OK even if I send to a land line or fake number. When will this return an error? I have not seen a case where it does.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out what was happening?

Comment: @n0rm9n no actually,It seemed like it was a carrier problem,And I couldn't find a solution for!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [sendTextMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) states:

> sentIntent:   if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is successfully sent, or failed. The result code will be Activity.RESULT_OK...

If you go look at [Activity.RESULT_OK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) the value is -1.

So the resultCode of -1 is actually RESULT_OK.

In general it is best not to look at numeric values but to try to figure out which constant they are representing.

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same in my code,I just said it returns -1 to make things brighter,I do use the Activity_RESULT_OK already ,I dont think there will be any difference though!Thanks for trying to help but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Consider editing your question to show us the receiving side of your code. As I said above, Activity.RESULT_OK is -1 so saying that it returns -1 is saying that the result was RESULT_OK. I think you are not understanding what the result means, but without the code on that side it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Yep! That's where the problem arises,I'm getting RESULT_OK even if the text message is not delivered nothing special in my BroadcastReceiver just a simple switch

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
private void sendSms(String phonenumber, String message) {
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SMS_SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

        int length = message.length();

        if (length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
            ArrayList<String> messagelist = manager.divideMessage(message);

            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

            int numParts = messagelist.size();
            ;
            for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
                sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                        new Intent(
                                SMS_SENT), 0));
                deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                        new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0));
            }

            manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null,
                    messagelist, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
        } else {
            manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, piSend,
                    piDelivered);
        }
}
```

and your Receiver:
note that use "Activity.RESULT_OK" instead number

```
private BroadcastReceiver deliveredreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String info = "Delivery information: ";

        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            info += "delivered";
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            info += "not delivered";
            break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

this permission use for sending and receiving sms.

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same in my code,I just said it return -1 to make things brighter,I don't need to divide messages nor use array of pending intents because my message length is about 5-6 characters! Other apps like GoSMS and the default sms messaging app determine it and give a failed status immediately! Thank you but this didn't solve my problem