# Measure the SMS send speed

Tags: android

I need to measure the send speed of SMS in an Android device. I'm thinking on the below approach. Please let me know if it is correct, or if there is a better solution.

Calculate the time spent sending 10 messages, and calculate the average time spent for sending each. But where is the speed amount here? Does the number of characters increase the time spent?

Here is the code I have written.

```
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1234567890",null,text,null,null);

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long result = endTime - startTime;
```

The `result` is 742 milliseconds, but I doubt that is correct. It means that each SMS only takes 74 milliseconds.

Comment: just for curiosity, what's wrong with 74ms? is it too long?

Comment: When I try sending SMS using device, it takes about 1.5 second to send.

Comment: You are assuming that the call is synchronous which I highly doubt. Most likley the 74ms are just for queuing the SMS in a outgoing queue, not actually establish a radio link with nearest base station and sending the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sendTextMessage()` method takes for its fourth parameter a `PendingIntent` that will fire when the message is sent. We can attach the current system time as an extra to the `Intent` for that `PendingIntent`, and when it fires, retrieve that extra and compare it to the current system time then. This will give us a decent measure of how long it takes to actually send the message.

We'll use a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the `PendingIntent`, simply retrieving the sent time extra in its `onReceive()`, and figuring the elapsed time from the current time there.

```
BroadcastReceiver smsSendReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long sentTime = intent.getLongExtra("sent_time", 0);
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - sentTime;
        Toast.makeText(context, elapsedTime + "ms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

We need to register this Receiver before we send the message. In an `Activity` or `Service`:

```
registerReceiver(smsSendReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
```

In sending our message, we'll kinda "cram" the `PendingIntent` construction right into the `sendTextMessage()` call, so we don't inadvertently introduce any unnecessary delay between grabbing the current time, and actually making the call.

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage("1234567890",
                   null,
                   "Testing...",
                   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                                              0,
                                              new Intent("SMS_SENT")
                                                  .putExtra("sent_time",
                                                            System.currentTimeMillis()),
                                              0),
                   null);
```

If desired, this can be run multiple times, and an average figured from the results. Be sure to handle the `PendingIntent`s appropriately if doing so, to ensure that the correct send time is delivered for each broadcast. In the given example, an easy way to do this is to use a different request code - the second argument in `getBroadcast()` - for each call.

It is advisable to unregister the Receiver when you're done with it, lest you get a nasty message in your logs about a leaked Receiver.

```
unregisterReceiver(smsSendReceiver);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Broadcast Receiver and update time once you got SMS SENT msg . then calculate each sms sent time . link may help [Android SMS Delivery Intent always return -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649805/android-sms-delivery-intent-always-return-1)